# How Can I Create A Symlink That Points To A Folder On A Remote Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link, remote-access, google-drive

I have Google Drive set up on Linux using the GNOME Online Accounts system. As such, my Google Drive is recognized by Nautilus as a remote file server, instead of a folder in the home directory as would be the case if the Google Drive app could be installed. I want to create a Symlink from a folder in my Google Drive to a folder in my Documents, so when I put something in there it's automatically backed up to Google Drive. How can I do this? I run 17.10 so there isn't a "Make Link" button in the right-click menu.

Comment: You can only create links to mounted filesystems, and to mount the Google Drive see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37234/mount-google-drive-in-linux).

Comment: I know how to mount Google Drive. I want to know about symlink creations because remote servers aren't stored in the media/user directory.

Comment: If this is mounted as a filesystem then use `ln`. If you can't use `ln`, then it is not mounted as a proper filesystem. Some apps/file explorers may make the file look like it's on a connected device (KDE's Dolphin, and possibly Nautilus) but this doesn't mean the remote file repository is "mounted".